# Looking to detect if key is pressed, execute action

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, batch-file, autohotkey

I am looking for a solution to my problem:

I have a program that launches a secondary program when a button is pressed, however this secondary program doesn't have a shortcut to exit. This means I have to exit fullscreen, go to file menu - exit.

I am looking for a way to press Esc that will then close the program.

The primary program is able to run ahk scripts when I click a button. I use this code to launch the secondary program when I select a button:

```
Process, Wait, test.exe, 10
Send !{Enter}
```

The above launches the secondary program, test.exe and tells it to go into fullscreen using alt+enter. This much works. However, adding the following doesn't work and breaks the script:

```
KeyWait, Esc
Send !{Enter}+!{f}+{x}
```

Adding the above launches the secondary program and closes it immediately. The script doesn't wait for a keypress at all.

Can anyone offer an alternative (whether AHK or not)? I can set the primary program to launch a bat file if necessary. All I need is a way to allow both programs to run as usual, with test.exe being the active window and to wait for Esc to be pressed at which point alt+enter followed by alt+f followed by x will be pressed which exits the secondary program.

Thank you

Comment: Create a shortcut to a batch file that uses taskkill to end the application. Though ESC by itself would not be ideal, because ESC is used in other context, you might use Shift-ESC or Alt-Esc. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill

Comment: But how would the batch file work? The bat wouldn't be the active window because i'm actively using the secondary program so the batch file has to listen passively for the keypress.

Comment: It was assumed you knew how to make a global keyboard shortcut in Windows, or with any alternative such as Claviere+ or AutoIt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyWait` is waiting for `Esc` to *not* be pressed (unless you use the `D` option), so it blows past that immediately.  If you want `Esc` to do something separately you can try `KeyWait` with the `D` option or make it a hotkey.

I'm going to list the hotkey method since that will be generally more useful to learn and use over the long run if you want to have multiple persistent functions available that don't require running or re-running the script.

`Main` in this case could also be replaced by a hotkey definition if desired so it would be re-triggerable without having to re-launch the script.  The `#Persistent` keyword at the top will keep the script loaded in memory with any hotkey definitions active after code execution hits the first `Return` statement and stops executing any code up front... after that the program will wait until you hit `Esc` and will then execute the associated code under that hotkey definition.  Any other desired hotkey definitions could be added in parallel with this code, which would trigger based on the hotkey definition.

If you want to make a hotkey definition specific to only operate when a certain program is active (i.e., not a global hotkey, but for a certain window or program), modify the `#IfWinActive` statement to selectively enable which program must be active for the hotkey to execute.

```
; Keeps the program in memory once it executes to the first Return statement
#Persistent

Main:
    Process, Wait, test.exe, 10
    Send !{Enter}
Return

#IfWinActive ; See Help contents for this keyword to selectively enable hotkeys
Esc::  
    ; This code could also be replaced by Process, Close, as noted in the other post
    Send !{Enter}+!{f}+{x}
Return
```

Comment: you sir or ma'am, are a miracle worker! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can close test.exe directly:

```
Process, Close, test.exe
```

This will kill test.exe, you can place it in your code.

Comment: I got an error on your line of code. says Failed to launch program or document Action: <test.exe> params: </im test.exe>.

What happens is the secondary program opens goes fullscreen then that error pops up. Esc key doesn't work.

Comment: Searched the docs and found that there are native way to kill programs, see the edits and place appropriately.